# Trouble starting new layout after button click

Tags: java, android

I am trying to make a fairly simple calculator app for getting familiar with android. My goal is to load a new interface with trig, logarithmic functions, etc. upon clicking the mode button on the xml layout file. I included activity in the manifest as well but it failed when I ran the project. What can I do so that it works?

Here is the main activity class:

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;

public class Calculator extends Activity implements OnClickListener{
public String str = "";
Character task = 'q';
double num, numtemp;
EditText showResult;
Button mode;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.display);
    showResult = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.result_id);
    mode = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bMode);
    mode.setOnClickListener(this);
}

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    if(v.getId() == R.id.bMode)
    {
        Intent i = new Intent("zero.paradox.valvemachine.SWITCHNODE");
        startActivity(i);
    }
}

public void btn1Clicked(View v) {
    insert(1);
}

public void btn2Clicked(View v) {
    insert(2);
}

public void btn3Clicked(View v) {
    insert(3);
}

public void btn4Clicked(View v) {
    insert(4);
}

public void btn5Clicked(View v) {
    insert(5);
}

public void btn6Clicked(View v) {
    insert(6);
}

public void btn7Clicked(View v) {
    insert(7);
}

public void btn8Clicked(View v) {
    insert(8);
}

public void btn9Clicked(View v) {
    insert(9);
}

public void btn0Clicked(View v){
    insert(0);
}

public void btnplusClicked(View v) {
    perform();
    task = '+';
}

public void btnminusClicked(View v) {
    perform();
    task = '-';
}

public void btndivideClicked(View v) {
    perform();
    task = '/';
}

public void btnmultiClicked(View v) {
    perform();
    task = '*';
}

public void btnequalClicked(View v) {
    calculate();
}

public void btnclearClicked(View v) {
    reset();
}

private void reset() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    str = "";
    task = 'q';
    num = 0;
    numtemp = 0;
    showResult.setText("");
}

private void insert(int j) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    str = str + Integer.toString(j);
    num = Integer.valueOf(str).intValue();
    showResult.setText(str);

}

private void perform() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    str = "";
    numtemp = num;
}

private void calculate() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    if (task == '+')
        num = numtemp + num;
    else if (task == '-')
        num = numtemp - num;
    else if (task == '/')
        num = numtemp / num;
    else if (task == '*')
        num = numtemp * num;
    showResult.setText("" + num);
    }

}
```

And the code for the new mode:

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;

public class SwitchMode extends Activity implements OnClickListener{

Button mode2;
EditText showResult2;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.display2);
    showResult2 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edtNode);
    mode2 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bMode);
    mode2.setOnClickListener(this);
}

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    if(v.getId() == R.id.mode)
    {
        Intent i = new Intent("org.calculator.MAINACTIVITY");
        startActivity(i);
    }
}

}
```

This is not working for me.. is there anything I can do to fix it?

Comment: define "not working for me"/

Comment: as a side note, you might want to look at finishing your activity (call `finish()`) when you start a new activity. the way you have it set up now, you will keep creating new activities each time the mode button is pressed, and the old activities will stay in the back stack. side note #2, a single FragmentActivity swapping out Fragments for each mode would be my preferred approach.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to starting another activity you have to create a `Intent intent = new Intent()` and indicate to this intent the activity you want to start with `setClass(Context packageContext, Class<?> cls)` method.

There are different ways to construct a intent, read the documentation. Everything is here :

- Reference: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html
- Training : http://developer.android.com/training/basics/firstapp/starting-activity.html

This is a part of your code after a clean up, try this :

```
    import android.app.Activity;
    import android.content.Intent;
    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.view.View;
    import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
    import android.widget.Button;
    import android.widget.EditText;

    public class Calculator extends Activity implements OnClickListener{

        private static EditText mShowResult;
        private static Button mMode;

        @Override
        public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

            setContentView(R.layout.display);

            mMode = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bMode);
            mShowResult = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.result_id);

            if (mMode != null) {
                mMode.setOnClickListener(this);
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            if(view == mMode) {
                Intent intent = new Intent();
                intent.setClass(this, SwitchMode.class);
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

The simplest solution is to use a different constructor for your Intents:

Change

`Intent i = new Intent("zero.paradox.valvemachine.SWITCHNODE");`

to

`Intent i = new Intent(getContext(), SwitchMode.class);`

Also, you misspelled your class name (switch**N**ode instead of switch**M**ode), which is probably why you are having the problem, as the constructor you are using *should* also work, I just prefer to use strongly typed class names over a String.